# MDX styling (next-mdx-remote) fails after I install Tailwind css in a Next.js app

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, mdxjs

I'm using [next-mdx-remote](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote) to make use of MDX in my Next.js project.

I've been following JetBrains WebStorm [guide](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2021/10/building-a-blog-with-next-js-and-mdx/) to build this, here they've used bootstrap as their CSS but my choice of CSS framework was tailwind css.

The thing is when I install tailwind css or any other CSS based on tailwind css like [flowbite](https://flowbite.com/), the MDX page loses it's styling.

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUL4N.png) 
[What I Get after adding tailwind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXmfQ.png)

- tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

- _app.tsx

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";
import Nav from "../components/Nav";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {/* <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://unpkg.com/@themesberg/flowbite@1.2.0/dist/flowbite.min.css"
        /> */}
      </Head>
      <Script src="https://unpkg.com/@themesberg/flowbite@1.2.0/dist/flowbite.bundle.js" />
      <Nav />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

- globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

- [blogId].tsx

```
// import fs from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import path from "path";
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote";

import { connectToDatabase } from "../../utils/mongodb";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

const BlogPg = ({ frontMatter: { title }, MDXdata }) => {
  return (
    <div className="px-5 md:px-80 py-10">
      <p className="text-5xl mb-4">{title}</p>
      <MDXRemote {...MDXdata} />
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

  let { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const posts = await db.collection("blogs").find({}).toArray();

  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: {
      blogId: post._id.toString(),
    },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { blogId } }) => {
  // const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(
  //   path.join("posts", blogId) + ".mdx",
  //   "utf-8"
  // );

  let { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const post = await db
    .collection("blogs")
    .find({ _id: new ObjectId(blogId) })
    .toArray();

  const { data: frontMatter, content } = matter(post[0].text);
  const MDXdata = await serialize(content);

  return {
    props: {
      frontMatter,
      blogId,
      MDXdata,
    },
  };
};

export default BlogPg;
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue - any luck?

Comment: nope it's like I'm not getting what's the issue!

Comment: I've bailed and reverted to bootstrap and [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/), which is a bummer. I've used bootstrap for so long - was hoping to try something new and Tailwind looks great. Might give it another swing later.

Comment: @rtoken answer's here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may change `content` to `purge` and add `require('@tailwindcss/typography')` to plugins in `tailwind.config.js`.
And then to see typography changes you should cover your `<MDXRemote .../>` with a `prose` named div.

- tailwind.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
      purge: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
    };
```

- [blogId].tsx

```
...

            <div className="prose">
    
              <MDXRemote {...MDXdata} /> 
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

...
```